# Closed form of $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} x^i (i!(i+1)!)^{-1/2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series, closed-form

I am looking for a closed form of this series
$$
\sum\limits_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{\sqrt{i!(i+1)!}},\:x \geq 0.
$$
The main problem is that this series contains roots of factorials. But many special functions just contain factorials, not their roots. Is it possible to express the sum of this series in some well-known (or little known) functions?

Comment: Why not rewrite it as 

$$\sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{x^i}{i! \sqrt{i+1}}$$

since you implicitly have an $(i!)^2$ under the square root? Of course, I don't know of a closed form for _this_ sum either (and neither do sage or wolframalpha, it looks like), but at least it's cleaner looking. For instance, it's the exponential generating function for the sequence $(n+1)^{-1/2}$

Comment: Your sum equals $$\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^1 \frac{e^{xt}}{\sqrt{-\log t}} \, {\rm d}t $$ in terms of an integral.

Comment: When we square each element of the sum, the closed form of the sum would be the  [regularized confluent hypergeometric function](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Hypergeometric0F1Regularized.html): $$\, _0{F}_1\left(2;x^2\right)/\Gamma(2)$$ Using this as a starting point, would it be possible to obtain a closed form for the original problem?

Comment: Using that $a^{-1/2} = \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty dy \; e^{-ay^2}$, I find that your sum is $ \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty dy\;\exp\left(xe^{-y^2}-y^2\right)$

Comment: Applying a standard trick translating the sum to a contour integral and then using Laplace's Method shows that the sum has the asymptotic behavior $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} \left(1 + O\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)\right)$.

Answer (score 4):

Like the comments mentioned, the sequence can be rewritten as

$$S(x) := \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{\sqrt{i!(i+1)!}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{\sqrt{i!i!(i+1)}} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!\sqrt{i+1}}$$

From here, I was able to give an approximation for this sum, using these lower and upper bounds:

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!\sqrt{i+1}} \le \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = e^x$$

And

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!\sqrt{i+1}} \ge \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!(i+1)} = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{(i+1)!} = \frac{1}{x}\sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} = \frac{1}{x}\left(\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{x^i}{i!} - 1\right) = \frac{e^x-1}{x}$$

So the sum always goes between the values

$$\frac{e^x-1}{x} \le S(x) \le e^x$$

From this, I guessed that maybe

$$S(x) \stackrel{?}{\approx} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}$$

And it turns out, yes, asymptotically, this indeed holds! I verified this using Python and MatPlotLib. I plotted $S(x)$ (summed up to $100$) in red and the $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}$ approximation in blue. The two plots are for the case $x \in [0,3]$ and $x \in [0,6]$. Only the begininning portion, about $x \in [0,0.5]$ is off.

[image: Plots]

I don't think it's easy to find a closed formula for this, WolframAlpha just gives up for example. So this might be the best we can get.

Of course, we might even be able to get better low-end approximations too with functions like

$$\frac{e^x - 1}{\sqrt{x}}, \quad \frac{e^x - x}{\sqrt{x}}, \quad \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} - x$$

Which I have tested, but none were significantly better than $\frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}$.

**EDIT:** Upon further trial and error, $S(x) \approx \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x+1}}$ might be even better, this one's even closer on the low end:

[image: Plot 2]

**EDIT $2$:**  I found this too. This is $S(x) \approx \frac{e^x + \sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{x+1}}$. This fits better on the high end, but worse on the low end.

[image: Plot 3]

Answer (score 3):

You will not find closed form, but using
$$n^{-s} = \frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-nt} \, {\rm d}t$$
for $s=1/2$ (it should work for general $s$) and substituting $e^{-t} \rightarrow t$, you can bound your sum above $$f(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{n!\sqrt{n+1}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{xt}}{\sqrt{-\log(t)}} \, {\rm d}t \stackrel{t=1-\tau}{=} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x\tau}}{\sqrt{-\log(1-\tau)}} \, {\rm d}\tau \\ \leq \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^1 \frac{e^{-x\tau}}{\sqrt{\tau}} \, {\rm d}\tau \stackrel{x\tau=u^2}{=} \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} \frac{2}{\sqrt{\pi}} \int_0^{\sqrt{x}} e^{-u^2} \, {\rm d}u \leq \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}}\, ,$$
where $-\log(1-t) \geq t$ was used.

You can find better approximations, by expanding
$$\frac{1}{\sqrt{-\ln(1-t)}} = \frac{1}{\sqrt{t}} - \frac{\sqrt{t}}{4} - \frac{7t^{3/2}}{96} + O\left(t^{5/2}\right)$$
about $t=0$, and which leads to

$$f(x)= \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{8x} - \frac{7}{128x^2} + O\left(1/x^3\right) \right) {\rm erf}\left( \sqrt{x} \right) + \frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi}} \left( \frac{31}{96x} + \frac{7}{64x^2} \right) \\
= \frac{e^x}{\sqrt{x}} \left( 1 - \frac{1}{8x} - \frac{7}{128x^2} + O\left(1/x^3\right) \right) \, .$$

Furthermore I played around via try and error an looked for smooth elementary functions that match $f(x)=1+\frac{x}{\sqrt{2}}+O(x^2)$ up to first order about $x=0$ and till second order asymptotically. My ansatz was
$$f(x)=e^x \sqrt{\frac{1+c/x+1/x^2}{x+a+b/x+1/x^2}}$$
and Taylor expanding about $x=0$ and $x=\infty$ gives the coefficients
$$a=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3}-\frac{7}{8} \\
b=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{3} + \frac{7}{8} \\
c=\frac{4\sqrt{2}}{3} - \frac{9}{8}$$
which approximates $f(x)$ reasonably well and bounds it from above. You can do much better by increasing the order inside the square-root from $1/x^2$ to $1/x^3$ and using the two new degrees of freedom to match up to third order about $x=0$. The expressions for the coefficients become more complicated though.

Here is a graph:

[image: Approximations for f(x)]

Comment: Remark: in terms of the generalised Bernoulli numbers (or Nörlund numbers) $$
\frac{1}{{\sqrt { - \log (1 - t)} }}= \sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(-1)^n\frac{{B_n^{(n - 1/2)} }}{{1 - 2n}}\frac{{t^{n - 1/2} }}{{n!}}} 
$$ for $|t|<1$. This yields and exact expansion in terms of the lower incomplete gamma function: $$
f(x) = \frac{{e^x }}{{\sqrt {\pi x} }}\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {(-1)^n\frac{{B_n^{(n - 1/2)} }}{{(1 - 2n)n!}}\frac{{\gamma (n + 1/2,x)}}{{x^n }}} .
$$ The divergent asymptotic series follows by noting that $\gamma (n + 1/2,x) \sim \Gamma (n + 1/2)$ for $x \gg 1$ and fixed $n$.

Comment: Do you have some explicit reference to these half-integer Nörlund numbers? I only find the integer indexed ones.

Comment: You can start [here](http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.16.i).